# how to use meteors collection.find() together with sort, skip and limit

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm writing a chat program using Meteor. I need to show the 10 most recent messages in ascending order.

```
Messages.find({...}, {sort: {created: 1}, skip: getMessageCount()-10, limit: 10});
```

This code shows me only the first 10 messages.

Does the skip parameter work in Meteor and I made a mistake, or are there any known bugs?

Answer (score 2):

The reason why it returns first 10 messages is: `{sort: {created: 1}}` , which return in ascending order of the value `created` attribute.

You should write `{sort: {created: -1}}`, ie. records with higher value of `created` will be returned first.

Also,  assuming that the `created` carries a valid date value along with the timestamp, you should insert its [`parsed`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parse.asp) value, in order to efficiently perform sorting based on date.

Comment: thank you for your answer. that was a typo in my post. in my codefile, i have `code`{sort: {created: -1}}`code`. but this gives me the latest message at first position. what i really want, is the latest message on the last position (at bottom), so that i have the last 10 messages on my site (sorting: asc) and skipping the rest. i hope this was good to understand. :)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to form on a server 
`Messages.find({...}, {sort: {created: -1}, limit: 10});`
And then on a client
`Messages.find({...}, {sort: {created: 1}})`
What here will happen:

1. You get from Mongo a splitting of 10 last messages but in a wrong
   order
2. You run formatting the right order on a client